# Predict long jump results: is this a time series forecasting problem or a regression problem?

Tags: machine-learning, model, time-series

Here is my data (simplified):

```
Athletics    Age    Competition    Result(m)
--------------------------------------------
Alex         10.2    CompA          3.2
Alex         11.5    CompB          4.3
...
Bob          9.9     CompC          3.5
Bob          10.7    CompD          5.6
...
Dave         10.3    CompB          5.2
Dave         11.6    CompD          6.3
....
```

So my data is about a set of children at different ages (8-28) the results of long jump in different competitions.

What I want to know:

1. Given a new child Paul, if we know his history (age 8 - 16 for example), how to forecast his future result (say at age 18, 20, 24)?
2. If we can group jumpers into A-E based on their best results, how to predict in which group Paul will be in the future (say when he is 18)?

I recently learned a bit about machine learning and deep learning, and I know this is a problem that can be solved using those models, but I'm confused what models I am supposed to use.

1. Am I supposed to do the forecasting for Paul (the new child) ONLY based on Paul's history data? Or I am supposed to do it using others' data like Alex, Bob, Dave?
2. Is this a time series forecasting problem, where I supposed to use models like ARIMA, ARCH, LSTM (RNN)?
3. Or this is a "normal" supervised or non-supervised regression or classification problem, where I supposed to use textbook models like Linear Regression, Logistic Regression, KNN, NB, DT, SVM, Random Forest, ANN, DNN, CNN?

Any direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is both. Regression just means there is no sigmoid activation on the output layer of the model. So you could use a time series model like LSTM or GRU (this may lead to overfitting to use such a complex model), then use them to perform regression. This way, the model will learn the way other children perform, then use the data for Paul to predict how well he will perform. This is not a classification problem! You are predicting continues value, not classes. This means it has to be regression.

I would suggest reading books or taking tutorials, I love Deep Learning with Python.

Comment: Thank you Milo! My research was that this is a question closed to "forecasting stock prices" rather than "bay area housing prices". What confused me the most is, in forecasting stock prices, you use historical data for stock A to forecast future price for stock A, no need to use any other data for stocks like B, C or D. But in my problem, am I supposed to use OTHER jumpers' data to forecast THIS jumper's future? Or I just use Paul's history to forecast Paul's future? Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help! If I've fully answered your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're trying to solve is usually called panel (or supervised) forecasting.

Whether or not to use data from other children is a practical question. You can compare models that use the data against models that use only Paul's data.

There is no need to use deep learning, but of course you can try. Other standard machine learning algorithm (random forest, etc.) or statistical forecasting algorithm (ARIMA, etc) can also be adapted to solve this kind of problem.

There are few libraries that solve this problem off-the-shelf. One is pysf with a tutorial on weather data (https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/pysf/blob/master/examples/Walkthrough.ipynb), another one is gluon-ts (mostly deep-learning methods).